# Как заархивировать папку в tempfile? | python

Tags: python

Есть папка, которая может весить достаточно много, для отправки по http ее надо заархивировать в tempfile

```py
import tempfile

temp_arc = compress_dir("/some_dir")

...отправка...

temp_arc.close()
```

Вот как `compress_dir` сделать?

Comment: Например, использовать функцию shutil.make_archive: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь библиотекой shutil и ее методом

```
make_archive(archive_name, 'zip', root_dir)
```

функция также возвращает путь к созданному архиву, ну и реализация будет примерно такой:

```
import tempfile 
from shutil import make_archive

temp_arc = make_archive('/myarchive', 'zip', '/somedir') 
… отправка …
```